# TinyMce Imagemanager: Could not find authenticator: SessionAuthenticator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

using .NET MVC 4
I am trying to secure imagemanager and in
in ~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/imagemanager/default.aspx I get:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Fatal: Could not find authenticator: SessionAuthenticator, 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: Moxiecode.Manager.ManagerException: Fatal: Could not find authenticator: SessionAuthenticator,
Source Error:

```
  Line 25:         page += "?domain=" + domain;
  Line 26: 
===>**Line 27:     **if (man.IsAuthenticated)****
  Line 28:         Response.Redirect("pages/" + man.Config["general.theme"] + "/" + page,     true);
  Line 29:     else
```

my Web.config in ~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/imagemanager is standard directly from the downloaded sources.

The full file which shows the error is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/plain" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Moxiecode.Manager" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Moxiecode.Manager.Utils" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Moxiecode.Manager.Authenticators" %>

<%
string type = Request["type"], page = Request["page"], domain = Request["domain"];
ManagerEngine man;

// Run install if it exists
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("install")))
    Response.Redirect("install/default.aspx", true);

if (type == null)
    Response.Redirect("examples.html", true);

// Setup file manager
man = new ManagerEngine(type, Path.GetDirectoryName(Request.PhysicalPath));

if (page == null)
    page = "index.html";

if (domain != null)
    page += "?domain=" + domain;

if (man.IsAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect("pages/" + man.Config["general.theme"] + "/" + page, true);
else
    Response.Redirect(man.Config["authenticator.login_page"] + "?return_url=" + Server.UrlEncode("" + Request.Url), true);
%>
```